# Set defaultCountdown jquery countdown to specfic time

Tags: jquery

I have a countdown timer set up to finish on the 1st of october.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Count/jquery.countdown.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function () {
        var austDay = new Date();
        austDay = new Date(2011, 10-1, 01)
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
        $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
    });
    </script>
```

However, how do i set it to finish not at midnight but at 9am on 1st October 2011?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

Just set all those.

Also, why are you doing 10-1? That is september, not october.

Comment: For some reason thats what i have to use to get it to the 1st of October

Comment: @Beginner Yah, I should have remembered that. Javascript months count from zero instead of 1. Confusing.

Comment: month of September is 9, month of October is 10 on a counting of 1. Why would 10 show October if counting from 0?